# Now am getting incompatible error when using the if else statements

Tags: java, switch-statement

trying to run the program below but am getting an error when using the switch method

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author kern
public class loans {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    //variabled decleared
    double rate, payment,principal,interest,n;
    int length;
    String period;

    //input
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of money borrowed: $");
    principal = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the annual interest rate: ");
    interest = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the payment period :");
    period = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Loan Length:");
    length = input.nextInt();
    //process

    rate=interest/100;
    payment= principal*(rate*Math.pow((1+rate),n)/ Math.pow ((1+rate),n));

      if (period==annually) {
               n=1*length;
                System.out.prtintf(Your monthly sum is %f:,payment);{

 if (period==semiannuall) {
               n=2*length;
                System.out.prtintf(Your monthly sum is %f:,payment);{

 if (period== quarterly) {
               n=4*length;
                System.out.prtintf(Your quarterly sum is %f:,payment);{

 if (period==monthly) {
               n=12*length;
                System.out.prtintf(Your monthly sum is %f:,payment);{




}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` as case value are supported from java 7

**See**

- [Switch case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

You need to use it like

```
if("annually".equals(period)){
}
```

Comment: am new to programming so what method should I use?

Comment: I didn't realize they added String as a case value.  But if that is the case perhaps updating your Java would solve the problem.  In the past I have always limited it to an int or a char for the case var.

Comment: @KernDennis or `if` / `else if` if you are just starting. Use the booleans `period.equals("monthly")`, etc.

Comment: netbeans is an ide ,its not related to methods in java,use if ,elseif as @irrelephant mentioned

Comment: when using if, else if am getting an error saying incompatible type

Answer (score 0):

Per Jigar Joshi link you can do strings now:

**Using Strings in switch Statements**

*In Java SE 7 and later, you can use a String object in the switch statement's expression. The following code example, StringSwitchDemo, displays the number of the month based on the value of the String named month:*

```
public class StringSwitchDemo {
public static int getMonthNumber(String month) {

    int monthNumber = 0;

    if (month == null) {
        return monthNumber;
    }

    switch (month.toLowerCase()) {
        case "january":
            monthNumber = 1;
            break;
        case "february":
            monthNumber = 2;
            break;
        case "march":
            monthNumber = 3;
            break;
        case "april":
            monthNumber = 4;
            break;
        case "may":
            monthNumber = 5;
            break;
        case "june":
            monthNumber = 6;
            break;
        case "july":
            monthNumber = 7;
            break;
        case "august":
            monthNumber = 8;
            break;
        case "september":
            monthNumber = 9;
            break;
        case "october":
            monthNumber = 10;
            break;
        case "november":
            monthNumber = 11;
            break;
        case "december":
            monthNumber = 12;
            break;
        default: 
            monthNumber = 0;
            break;
    }

    return monthNumber;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String month = "August";

    int returnedMonthNumber =
        StringSwitchDemo.getMonthNumber(month);

    if (returnedMonthNumber == 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid month");
    } else {
        System.out.println(returnedMonthNumber);
    }
}
```

}